# C# program opens Word docx (not doc) from command line, fails in Jenkins

Tags: c#, jenkins, ms-word, office-interop

Running on Windows 10
I have a C# program that (among other things) opens, modifies, and writes a Word document (docx, not doc).
It works fine from the command line.
But run in Jenkins, the Documents.Open() call returns null

I have read the following on StackOverflow:
[Unable to open word document from jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30392115/unable-to-open-word-document-from-jenkins)
[open word doc with c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786999/open-word-doc-with-c-sharp)
[Interop.Word Documents.Open is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10837437/interop-word-documents-open-is-null)

I have added C:\Windows\System32\config\systemfile\Desktop and C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemfile\Desktop
Result: program hangs on Documents.Open (System32 didn't change anything; SysWOW64 resulted in the hang)

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

// … lots of stuff

var wordApplication = new Word.Application();

wordApplication.Visible = false;
Word.Application wordApp = null;
if (wordApplication != null)
    wordApp = wordApplication as Word.Application;
Word.Document wordDoc = null;
if (wordApp != null){
    if(!IsFileinUse(reportPath))
    {
        // this line is the problem.
        // It works from the command line
        // In Jenkins, it either returns null or hangs
        wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(reportPath.FullName);
    }
}
```

I expect it to behave in Jenkins as it does from Command Prompt: open the file successfully and allow the operations -- not hang or return null.

Comment: Why are you using office interop and not [OpenXML](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/)? Office interop [is not supported for servier side applications](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office) like jenkins.

Comment: You cannot run *interactive* applications as BACKGROUND process. Maybe if you suprime the *open* step, your program could be work